# How to filter API response in JS

Tags: javascript, filter

my js code:

```
    /* To Call API and generate table function */
function getData() {
    let input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
        getDataFromAPI().then((response)=>{
                    response.data.filter(e => e.kolegij.toLowerCase() === input).forEach((data) => {
        generateTableData(data)
        
      });
        })
    }

/* TO generate Table Data */
function generateTableData(data){
    var sel = document.querySelector('#table-body');
    sel.innerHTML +=`<tr>
            <td>${data.kolegij}</td>
            <td>${data.ects}</td>
            <td>${data.sati}</td>
            <td>${data.predavanja}</td>
            <td>${data.vjezbe}</td>
            <td>${data.tip}</td>
            </tr>`
    }
    
/* To call an api function */
async function getDataFromAPI(){
        const response = await fetch("https://www.fulek.com/data/api/supit/curriculum-list/hr", {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
            Authorization:
              "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQXBvb0JHIiwibmJmIjoxNjc0MzMyMDM4LCJleHAiOjE2NzQzMzU2MzgsImlhdCI6MTY3NDMzMjAzOH0.4USsfZa1cHhA2eKyEEiuNYmWE8Gfq2SQy47KQSFsq3Y",
          },
        })
        return response.json();
    }
```

Once I get the response from the API I generate table with it's data, however, I want to add a filter function which for some reason doesn't work. Without the filter option everything is fine, I also debugged and the input is the correct value from the HTML document but I guess my direction is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs to also be transformed to `toLowerCase()` otherwise the user will have to write only in lowercase to be able to match an item from the request response.

```js
/* To Call API and generate table function */
function getData() {
  let input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
  getDataFromAPI().then((response) => {
    const res = response.data.filter(e => e.kolegij.toLowerCase() === input.toLowerCase()).forEach((data) => {
      generateTableData(data)
    });
  })
}

/* TO generate Table Data */
function generateTableData(data) {
  var sel = document.querySelector('#table-body');
  sel.innerHTML += `<tr>
            <td>${data.kolegij}</td>
            <td>${data.ects}</td>
            <td>${data.sati}</td>
            <td>${data.predavanja}</td>
            <td>${data.vjezbe}</td>
            <td>${data.tip}</td>
            </tr>`
}

/* To call an api function */
async function getDataFromAPI() {
  const response = await fetch("https://www.fulek.com/data/api/supit/curriculum-list/hr", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
      Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQXBvb0JHIiwibmJmIjoxNjc0MzMyMDM4LCJleHAiOjE2NzQzMzU2MzgsImlhdCI6MTY3NDMzMjAzOH0.4USsfZa1cHhA2eKyEEiuNYmWE8Gfq2SQy47KQSFsq3Y",
    },
  })
  return response.json();
}

getData();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Građa računala" id="searchBar"/>

<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Although, I get an error message: `testoo.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined
    at onload` because of the .filter extension. When I remove that, the error is gone. How can I filter it?